# Localizing Google Maps when the API file isn't called

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, localization

According to Google's documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Localization) and much of the internet, to localize Google Maps you just add the "language" parameter to the API JS file (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js), as long as you're using version 3+

For example:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=es

However, a site I'm working on doesn't call this API file. The first Google Maps-related file it calls is this JS:
https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/19/0/main.js

Does anyone know how to localize Google Maps when it calls this main.js file? I've already tried adding "language" and "hl" parameters, with no luck.

Comment: Do you have a call to this JS file in a `<script>` tag? Or do you see it loaded in your network console? You should be using `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=es`

Answer (score 0):

The maps api has a separate js file for each language, and the localization is part of the url, not the query string. ie:

https://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/18/15a/intl/es_ALL/main.js

When you are referencing the file:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=es  it bootstraps the above version behind the scenes.